# Gridview items as squares in WinRT (metro)

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I've been struggeling with this a few days now and can't get it to work. 
Maybe I'm not as good XAML programmer that I hoped I would be :)

Anyhow, my problem is that i want to bind a number of elements to a GridView and make them appear as squares without setting any width and height. The reason for this is that I want my GridView items to grow/shrink and expand to maximum size as the resolution or screen size vary.

Here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="MyItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <!--<Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}" />-->
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
        <Border CornerRadius="4" 
                BorderBrush="Black"  
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="Blue">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">X</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MyItemsPanelTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">
    <GridView x:Name="MyGrid"
              UseLayoutRounding="True"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"
              ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MyItemsPanelTemplate}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemContainerStyle}"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

And this is my code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
{
    public BlankPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        MyGrid.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Content = 1 });
        MyGrid.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Content = 2 });
        MyGrid.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Content = 3 });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

This however produces an output like this (rectangular items, not squares):

[image: Ouput]

I would appreciate if someone who knows a bit more about XAML and WinRT (metro) development than I do, could explain this for me and maybe give me a working example.

Thanx!

**EDIT**

I got a tip to wrap my Border in a Viewbox as it seems to have some scaling/stretching abilities.

I played around a couple of hours but I can't really get it to work 100%.

This is my XAML now:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

<Style x:Key="MyItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
    <Viewbox>
        <Border CornerRadius="3" 
        BorderBrush="Black"  
        BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid Background="Blue" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">X</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MyItemsPanelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">
    <GridView x:Name="MyGrid"
      UseLayoutRounding="True"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"
      ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MyItemsPanelTemplate}"
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemContainerStyle}"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

This produces this output:

[image: output2]

Now it seems to stretch itself to a sqaure, but it sretches itself outside the screen. I also ran this example in several resoultions and screen sizes and it shows the same output, which means it scales correctly.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Your commented out binding is close to something that could sort of work - only you would need to bind to ActualWidth:

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Overall I would suggest using hardcoded values - they make things easier on the CPU to layout, easier to deterministically design and will get scaled by Windows when screen size and resolution will require that. If you want more control over that - you can bind both Width and Height to the same value from a view model that you change depending on the need or write a converter that will convert a hardcoded Width/Height value to actual value depending on detected screen size/resolution or settings.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.
However the property binding for height wont work, neither with width or with actualwidth (that's why it is commented out).
Windows 8 will resize the elements according to given resolution, but will not resize them if I get a larger screen (with same resolution). This to me is logical since if I specify that my Squares should be 50x50px they will stay the same regardless of the screen size since the total amount of pixels are the same. If you run the built in tablet-simulator in VS11 you will see this.

........

Comment: I could keep my Height and Width values in a ViewModel and have a converter that converts these values as needed depending on screen size. But this is what I'm trying to avoid. Firstly I don't like having GUI logic in my ViewModels (it belongs to the View). Secondly, how many screen sizes should I adapt to? It will be a messy converter.

All I want is my squares to expand as much as they can.

And, can someone explain to me why they come in rectangluar shape? Is this a built in style for the GridView? I thought at least they would stretch themself across the screen? What is restraining them?

Comment: You don't need to have converter input in the vm, you can specify them explicitly in XAML.

Comment: Wouldn't it still be alot of "settings" for different screen sizes and something that would need to be maintained. I would rather have something that works without this.

Comment: Well, you have to decide to either let WinRT scale things for you or try to override it with your own approach... You should probably read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx